# How can I disable real-time validations in react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

I am using the Field component, to which I pass the validations that I need.
In the example below, in the validate prop I pass a regex to validate that it only contains letters.
The problem is that validations are always done in real time when the  field is updated, and I need it to only happen when I lose focus on the field. Is there any way to be able to do this?

```
<Field
                  name="name"
                  component={TextInput}
                  placeholder="Name"                      
                  validate={inputContainsOnlyWords}
                  
                />
```

Comment: You can add a timeout function to `inputContainsOnlyWords` so that it runs after a certain time. Instead of using `validate`, you can use `onChange`  too and run the validation in there

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938495/input-validation-settimeout-in-reactjs

Comment: You can enable validation on blur for the whole form using validateOnBlur prop https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FormProps#validateonblur